# Cordova: Touch event not recognized

Tags: android, events, cordova

We want to build an android app with Cordova. The problem is now, that when we click on an element that has style.display == none it should be style.display == block and backwards.
But this event is only triggered, if we tap twice on this element, so the first tap is not recognized.

```
<a href="javascript:klappDiv('togglemeldeort');" class="colorlessLabel">
            <p id='p05' class="myEtikett">
                <br>
            </p></a>
```

the function "klappDiv" is implemented as followed:

```
function klappDiv(element){
             if(document.getElementById(element).style.display == 'none')
              document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'block';
             else
                   document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'none';
        }
```

We tested it on some android devices and on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is properly select the element you want to work with.

If you look closely to your code, you are looking for an ID named 'togglemedeort' because this is the parameter that you are passing from your function on the `a` tag to the javascript

```
    function klappDiv(element)
```

resulting on this:

```
    function klappDiv(togglemedeort) {...}
```

So the line

```
    document.getElementById(element)
```

is actually being read as

```
    document.getElementById(togglemedeort) but you don't have any element with that ID.
```

I assume from your code that you are trying to modify the display of the `p` tag which is a child node of your `a` tag.

Being said that, a workmate and I came up with this solution that effectively change the display attribute of the `p` tag

```
function klappDiv(element) {
    var e = element.querySelector('p');
    console.log(e);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/cp288/

Hope it helps!